# how to edit user's profile variable (from web.config) while specifying user?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

This is how I edit the profile variables for a currently logged in user:
`Profile.variablename = "this";`

How can I do the same thing, but specifying the username whose profile variable I want to change, as opposed to just the currently logged in user?

Something like `Profile.variablename.("username", "this")` is what I'm looking for.

I'm using C# asp.net, thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

You can retrieve a specific profile with the `Profile.GetProfile()` method:

```
ProfileCommon profile = Profile.GetProfile(username);
profile.variablename = "this";
```